# Difference between embeds_many and has_many in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Can anyone explain to me the difference between `embeds_many` and `has_many` in mongoid?

Comment: No idea was this was voted down.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`embeds_many` is used to store relative documents inside of parent document.

`has_many` is used to store a relation between documents in separate collections. Relative records of `has_many` have field that stores id of the parent document.

Comment: when I have User and Post  models can I embed only user name and id. to make a link for example to users profile.

Comment: And I don't think `embeds_many` records can be found directly using the model e.g. Post.find(1). You have to find the parent record first, and then look for the child through the parent e.g. `user = User.find(1); user.posts.find(1)`

Comment: I just discovered this myself! I was using embeds many, when I should have been using has_many!!